# how to hide Aframe source code from the browser view source code or inspect element

Tags: dom, hide, aframe, webvr

I has build WebVR application using Aframe and i feel major issue with aframe is that source code is easily available please give me a solution to **hide source code**. how to secure my WebVr application source code which is a best way for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide the source but can [minimize your JavaScript](https://www.imperva.com/learn/performance/minification/). An A-Frame experience is like any other Web application and can be inspected by the browser's developer tools.